# Artificial Intelligence 8 Puzzle Solver Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, solver, sliding-tile-puzzle

Due to a problem with turtle, this program slows down as time goes on. I'm trying to fix that issue, but it should work otherwise. I know that changes need to be made in `def play()`, but I'm not exactly sure how. I'm trying to find a quicker way to run this and any and all feedback is much appreciated!

```
import math  
import turtle  
import random

class Puzzle:
def __init__(self, sideLength, x, y, col):
    self.cells = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 0]]
    self.SIZE = 100
    self.posX = 0
    self.posY = 0
    self.t = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.delay(0)
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    self.SIZE = sideLength
    self.posX = x
    self.posY = y
    self.t.width = 4
    self.t.hideturtle()
    self.t.speed(0)
    self.t.color(col,'white')
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.goto(0,0)
    self.t.pendown()

def drawSquare(self, t, side):
    [x,y] = self.t.position()
    self.t.pendown()
    self.t.begin_fill()
    self.t.begin_poly()
    for s in range(4):
        self.t.forward(side)
        self.t.right(90)
    self.t.end_poly()
    self.t.end_fill()
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.goto(x,y)
    self.t.pendown()        

def isGoal(self):
    temp = []
    for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])

    if temp[0]==0:
        for i in range(8):
            if temp[i]>temp[i+1]:
                return False
        return True
    if temp[-1]==0:
        for i in range(7):
            if temp[i]>temp[i+1]:
                return False
        return True         
    else:
        return False

def solvable(self):
    temp = []
    for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])
    inv_count = 0;
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(temp)):
            if temp[j]!=0 and temp[i]!=0 and temp[i] > temp[j]:
                inv_count += 1
    return (inv_count%2==0)

def shuffle(self):
    temp = []
    for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        r = random.randint(0, len(temp)-1)
        t = temp[i]
        temp[i] = temp[r]
        temp[r] = t

    for i in range(len(temp)):
        self.cells[i//3][i%3] = temp[i]

def utility(self):
    manhattan_dist = 0
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            tile = self.cells[row][col]
            if tile == 0:
                    continue
            finalRow = (tile-1)//3
            finalCol = (tile-1)%3
            manhattan_dist += abs(row-finalRow)+abs(col-finalCol)
    return manhattan_dist

def display(self):
    print(self.cells)

def up(self, visible):
    found = False
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if self.cells[row][col]==0:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break
    if row==2:
        return False
    else:
        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row+1][col]
        self.cells[row+1][col] = 0
        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row+1, col, row, col)
        return True

def down(self, visible):
    found = False
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if self.cells[row][col]==0:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break
    if row==0:
        return False
    else:
        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row-1][col]
        self.cells[row-1][col] = 0
        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row-1, col, row, col)
        return True

def left(self, visible):
    found = False
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if self.cells[row][col]==0:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break
    if col==2:
        return False
    else:
        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row][col+1]
        self.cells[row][col+1] = 0

        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row, col+1, row, col)
        return True

def right(self, visible):
    found = False
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if self.cells[row][col]==0:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break

    if col==0:
        return False
    else:
        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row][col-1]
        self.cells[row][col-1] = 0
        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row, col-1, row, col)
        return True

def displayWin(self, count):
    self.t.penup()      
    outputX = self.posX
    outputY = self.posY - 5 *self.SIZE
    self.t.goto(outputX, outputY)
    self.t.pendown()
    self.t.write("Solved in " + str(count) + " moves!", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", int(0.75*self.SIZE), "normal"))  

def updateBoard(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):
    self.t.penup()      
    topLeftX = self.posX + col1*self.SIZE
    topLeftY = self.posY - row1*self.SIZE
    self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
    self.t.pendown()
    self.drawSquare(self.t, self.SIZE)
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.right(90)
    self.t.forward(self.SIZE)
    self.t.left(90)
    self.t.forward(self.SIZE/2)
    self.t.pendown()
    if self.cells[row1][col1] != 0:
        self.t.write(self.cells[row1][col1], move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", int(0.75*self.SIZE), "normal"))
    self.t.penup()      
    topLeftX = self.posX + col2*self.SIZE
    topLeftY = self.posY - row2*self.SIZE
    self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
    self.t.pendown()
    self.drawSquare(self.t, self.SIZE)
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.right(90)
    self.t.forward(self.SIZE)
    self.t.left(90)
    self.t.forward(self.SIZE/2)
    self.t.pendown()
    if self.cells[row2][col2] != 0:
        self.t.write(self.cells[row2][col2], move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", int(0.75*self.SIZE), "normal"))
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.goto(0,0)
    self.t.pendown()


def drawBoard(self):
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            self.t.penup()      
            topLeftX = self.posX + col*self.SIZE
            topLeftY = self.posY - row*self.SIZE
            self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
            self.drawSquare(self.t, self.SIZE)
            self.t.penup()
            self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
            self.t.right(90)
            self.t.forward(self.SIZE)
            self.t.left(90)
            self.t.forward(self.SIZE/2)
            self.t.pendown()
            if self.cells[row][col] != 0:
                self.t.write(self.cells[row][col], move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", int(0.75*self.SIZE), "normal"))
    self.t.penup()
    self.t.goto(0,0)
    self.t.pendown()

def play():
p = Puzzle(50, 0, 0, 'blue')
p.shuffle()
while(not p.solvable()):
        p.shuffle() 
p.display()

p.drawBoard()
prevMove = 1
count = 0
while (not p.isGoal()):
            #Create a new puzzle and copy the current state to it
    q = Puzzle(30,-200,200, 'red')
    #p.display()
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            q.cells[row][col] = p.cells[row][col]
    # Disable this next line if you don't want to display this board
    q.drawBoard()
    bestMove = 0
    minimum = 1000
    validMoves = []
    # Try out all possible moves on the new puzzle and choose the one that leads to the lowest utility
    # Make the q method calls with False if you don't want to display this board
    if q.down(True):
        validMoves.append(0)
        bestMove = 0
        minimum = q.utility()
        q.up(True)
    if q.right(True):
        validMoves.append(1)
        if q.utility()<minimum:
            minimum = q.utility()
            bestMove = 1
        q.left(True)
    if q.up(True):
        validMoves.append(2)
        if q.utility()<minimum:
            minimum = q.utility()
            bestMove = 2
        q.down(True)
    if q.left(True):
        validMoves.append(3)
        if q.utility()<minimum:
            minimum = q.utility()
            bestMove = 3
        q.right(True)

    # If the best move is the opposite of the one just taken...
    if(abs(bestMove - prevMove)==2): #UP and DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT are numbered 2 values apart
                    #... flip a coin and if it is heads...
        r = random.randint(1,2)
        #... remove the best move from the list of valid moves...
        validMoves.remove(bestMove)
        if r == 1:
                            # Randomly choose one of the other valid moves
            index = random.randint(0, len(validMoves)-1)
            bestMove = validMoves[index]
                            # If the coin shows tails, then allow the solver to backtrack over the last move
    if bestMove==0:
        p.down(True)
        print('down',p.utility())
        count += 1
    elif bestMove==1:
        p.right(True)
        print('right', p.utility())
        count += 1
    elif bestMove==2:
        p.up(True)
        print('up', p.utility())
        count += 1
    else:
        p.left(True)
        print('left', p.utility())
        count += 1
    prevMove = bestMove;
    print(count)
print('Solved in ' + str(count) + ' moves')
p.displayWin(count)
#mov = input()


play()
```

Comment: What is your question about this code? Please spell out what it's doing that you want to change (beyond the performance issue that you seem to be suggesting is a secondary problem).

Comment: It runs fast without problems if you don't draw anything, but I suppose you already found that out.

Comment: Thank you!im wondering if there’s a way to draw it faster or a different way to present the board in a performance way rather than just printing the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since graphics are your bottleneck, make sure at runtime, the graphics do as little work as possible.  In your code, at runtime, you move the turtle to the correct location, draw a new square with a white interior, adjust the position slightly, and draw a number.  Instead, let's leave the grid alone and create a matrix of turtles all at the correct locations to clear and draw a new number:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, sideLength, x, y, color):
        self.cells = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]
        self.markers = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
        self.t = Turtle(visible=False)
        self.s = Screen()
        self.s.tracer(False)
        self.SIZE = sideLength
        self.font = ("Arial", int(0.75 * self.SIZE), "normal")
        self.posX, self.posY = x, y
        self.t.width = 4
        self.t.speed('fastest')
        self.t.color(color, 'white')

    def drawSquare(self, side):
        position = self.t.position()

        self.t.pendown()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.t.forward(side)
            self.t.right(90)

        self.t.penup()
        self.t.goto(position)
        self.t.pendown()

    def isGoal(self):
        temp = []

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])

        if temp[0] == 0:
            for i in range(8):
                if temp[i] > temp[i + 1]:
                    return False
            return True

        if temp[-1] == 0:
            for i in range(7):
                if temp[i] > temp[i + 1]:
                    return False
            return True

        return False

    def solvable(self):
        temp = []

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])

        inv_count = 0

        for i in range(len(temp)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(temp)):
                if temp[j] != 0 and temp[i] != 0 and temp[i] > temp[j]:
                    inv_count += 1

        return inv_count % 2 == 0

    def shuffle(self):
        temp = []

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                temp.append(self.cells[row][col])

        for i in range(len(temp)):
            r = random.randint(0, len(temp) - 1)
            t = temp[i]
            temp[i] = temp[r]
            temp[r] = t

        for i in range(len(temp)):
            self.cells[i // 3][i % 3] = temp[i]

    def utility(self):
        manhattan_dist = 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                tile = self.cells[row][col]
                if tile == 0:
                    continue
                finalRow = (tile - 1) // 3
                finalCol = (tile - 1) % 3
                manhattan_dist += abs(row - finalRow) + abs(col - finalCol)

        return manhattan_dist

    def display(self):
        print(self.cells)

    def up(self, visible):
        found = False
        row, col = 0, 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if self.cells[row][col] == 0:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break

        if row == 2:
            return False

        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row + 1][col]
        self.cells[row + 1][col] = 0

        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row + 1, col, row, col)

        return True

    def down(self, visible):
        found = False
        row, col = 0, 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if self.cells[row][col] == 0:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break

        if row == 0:
            return False

        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row - 1][col]
        self.cells[row-1][col] = 0

        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row - 1, col, row, col)

        return True

    def left(self, visible):
        found = False
        row, col = 0, 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if self.cells[row][col] == 0:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break

        if col == 2:
            return False

        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row][col + 1]
        self.cells[row][col + 1] = 0

        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row, col + 1, row, col)

        return True

    def right(self, visible):
        found = False
        row, col = 0, 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if self.cells[row][col] == 0:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break

        if col == 0:
            return False

        self.cells[row][col] = self.cells[row][col - 1]
        self.cells[row][col - 1] = 0

        if visible:
            self.updateBoard(row, col - 1, row, col)

        return True

    def displayWin(self, count):
        self.t.penup()
        outputX = self.posX
        outputY = self.posY - 5 * self.SIZE
        self.t.goto(outputX, outputY)
        self.t.pendown()
        self.t.write("Solved in " + str(count) + " moves!", move=False, align="center", font=self.font)

    def updateBoard(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):

        data = self.cells[row1][col1] or ''
        marker = self.markers[row1][col1]
        marker.undo()
        marker.write(data, align="center", font=self.font)
        self.s.update()  # don't rely on this happening as a side effect of other turtle functions

        data = self.cells[row2][col2] or ''
        marker = self.markers[row2][col2]
        marker.undo()
        marker.write(data, align="center", font=self.font)
        self.s.update()

    def drawBoard(self):

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                self.t.penup()

                topLeftX = self.posX + col * self.SIZE
                topLeftY = self.posY - row * self.SIZE
                self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
                self.drawSquare(self.SIZE)

                self.t.penup()
                self.t.goto(topLeftX, topLeftY)
                self.t.right(90)
                self.t.forward(self.SIZE)
                self.t.left(90)
                self.t.forward(self.SIZE / 2)

                data = self.cells[row][col] if self.cells[row][col] != 0 else ''
                marker = self.t.clone()
                marker.write(data, align="center", font=self.font)

                self.markers[row][col] = marker

        self.t.penup()
        self.t.goto(0, 0)
        self.t.pendown()

def play():
    p = Puzzle(50, 0, 0, 'blue')
    p.shuffle()
    while not p.solvable():
        p.shuffle()
    p.display()

    p.drawBoard()
    prevMove = 1
    count = 0

    q = Puzzle(30, -200, 200, 'red')
    q.drawBoard()

    while not p.isGoal():
        # Copy the current state to new puzzle (probably should be a method)

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                q.cells[row][col] = p.cells[row][col]

                data = q.cells[row][col] or ''
                marker = q.markers[row][col]
                marker.undo()
                marker.write(data, align="center", font=q.font)
        q.s.update()

        bestMove = 0
        minimum = 1000
        validMoves = []

        # Try out all possible moves on the new puzzle and choose the one that leads to the lowest utility
        # Make the q method calls with False if you don't want to display this board
        if q.down(True):
            validMoves.append(0)
            bestMove = 0
            minimum = q.utility()
            q.up(True)

        if q.right(True):
            validMoves.append(1)
            if q.utility() < minimum:
                minimum = q.utility()
                bestMove = 1
            q.left(True)

        if q.up(True):
            validMoves.append(2)
            if q.utility() < minimum:
                minimum = q.utility()
                bestMove = 2
            q.down(True)

        if q.left(True):
            validMoves.append(3)
            if q.utility() < minimum:
                minimum = q.utility()
                bestMove = 3
            q.right(True)

        # If the best move is the opposite of the one just taken...
        if abs(bestMove - prevMove) == 2:  # UP and DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT are numbered 2 values apart
            #... flip a coin and if it is heads...
            r = random.randint(False, True)
            #... remove the best move from the list of valid moves...
            validMoves.remove(bestMove)
            if r:
                # Randomly choose one of the other valid moves
                index = random.randint(0, len(validMoves) - 1)
                bestMove = validMoves[index]
                # If the coin shows tails, then allow the solver to backtrack over the last move

        if bestMove == 0:
            p.down(True)
            print('down', p.utility())
            count += 1
        elif bestMove == 1:
            p.right(True)
            print('right', p.utility())
            count += 1
        elif bestMove == 2:
            p.up(True)
            print('up', p.utility())
            count += 1
        else:
            p.left(True)
            print('left', p.utility())
            count += 1

        prevMove = bestMove
        print(count)

    print('Solved in ' + str(count) + ' moves')
    p.displayWin(count)

play()
```

I've also done some other code cleanup as well, that may, or may not, affect performance.

Comment: You are a wonderful human being. Thank you very much! Also, what IDE do you use for python? What's the best?

Comment: @cdev, I don't use any IDE, I'm strictly old school -- I simply use TextEdit on OS X in Plain Text mode.  The best IDE is the one you take the time to learn really well.

Comment: Many repeated moves: for instance - left 7
2104
right 8
2105
left 7
2106
right 8
2107
left 7
2108
right 8
left 7
2104
right 8
2105
left 7
2106
right 8
2107
left 7
2108
right 8

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, you should address that to the OP, not to me.  The question was about turtle display efficiency (as further clarified by the OP in the comments to the question) and I believe I addressed that.  The efficiency of the OP's puzzle solver is another issue completely.

Comment: Yes, I agree @cdlane; my comment was, in fact, for the OP, and not directly related to the question asked; sorry it wasn't clear; maybe I should have addressed it? Here, have somme good rep for your answer.